# How does parenthesis operator overlaoding work in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I've following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class Matrix
{
private:
    double m_data[3][3]{};

public:
    double& operator()(int row, int col);
};

double& Matrix::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    assert(col >= 0 && col < 3);
    assert(row >= 0 && row < 3);

    return m_data[row][col];
}

int main()
{
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix(1, 2) = 4.5;
    std::cout << matrix(1, 2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering how does following line assigns the `4.5` to `m_data[1][2]`.

`matrix(1, 2) = 4.5;`

Actually, there is no assignment inside the function `double& operator()(int row, int col)`. It has only `return m_data[row][col];` statement. Shouldn't it just return value at `m_data[1][2]`. In that case it would be `0` by default.

Comment: It returns a `double&` which can be assigned to with the built in `operator=(double)`

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a value (`double`) and a reference (`double&`)?

Comment: Do you understand that `double& x = matrix(1,2); x = 4.5;` does that assignment?

Comment: The title does not match the misconception expressed in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```cpp
double& Matrix::operator()(int row, int col)
```

return a reference of a `double` variable, not just a value.

```cpp
matrix(1, 2) = 4.5;
```

`matrix(1, 2)` returns a reference of that variable, and that reference get assigned a value, that is `4.5`